# Micro service communication solution in the Azure service fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Recently I started working on an old `Azure` cloud based micro service project, which is running on `Azure Service Fabric` platform.

(I'm new to this platform, also I don't have team members for discussion. I can read the code and document to understand this project.)

I roughly understand how Service Fabric works. But one question confuses me a lot about `inter service communications`. I want to know which inter service communication solution my project is using.

Here are some useful information about this point:

0. Suppose the Azure Service Fabric cluster endpoint is as follows: `myTestCluster.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000`
1. The project use `Consul` for service discovery. In the codebase, before sending request to other services, first need to get the registered URL from consul. And the URL resolved from `Consul` is something as follows: `myTestCluster.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:23333`, which is another service deployed and run on the cluster. The code for sending request is something like:

```cs
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(uri); // uri is resolved from Consul
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

I read some [article](https://dzimchuk.net/re-iterating-communication-options-in-service-fabric/) and know that the potential inter-service communication methods are:

1. Service Fabric's Naming service: based on the method I shown above, I think it's not this one.
2. Reverse proxy
3. DNS service

But I can't tell out method 2 or 3, which one is used. Or any other ones?

Comment: Based on this information, it seems that your project is not using Service Fabric's Naming Service for inter-service communication. Additionally, the URL resolved from Consul is in the format of a hostname and port number (myTestCluster.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:23333), which suggests that it is not using a reverse proxy or a DNS service.

Comment: @Sourav, yes, after long time debugging. I noticed that the service is not using any inter-service communication methods mentioned above. 

The URL matches the Service Fabric's load balancer's url. And I also find the load balancing rule configured on Azure. For example, the load balancer's port 23333 is mapped to VM(virtual machine)'s port, let's say also 23333. And set the port in the manifest file of this service as 23333 too, to make sure the service is running on this port.